# Masking image that contains alpha makes the inner mask black

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I'm trying to mask a background image that is smaller than the mask. and the space between the background and mask appears black.

[image: mask and background]

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
     batch.end();
     batch.begin();     
     Gdx.gl20.glColorMask(false, false, false, true);
     batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ZERO);
     batch.draw(mask, getX(), getY());
     batch.flush();
     Gdx.gl20.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);      
     batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_DST_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);        
     batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY());       
     batch.flush();
     batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
     batch.end();
     batch.begin();
```

I tried all kind function combinations without any success. probably i'm missing something.

**Update**

Attaching chart that I build of all possible (relevant) results of src and dst blending function. Fortunately none of the below is working, and as I guessed there is something more need to be done in order to achieve the result.

```
     Gdx.gl20.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);      
     batch.setBlendFunction(src_func, dst_func);        
     batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY());
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very detailed and informative question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it using FrameBuffer.

```
    batch.end();
    spriteBatch.begin();
        buffer.begin();
            Gdx.gl20.glColorMask(false, false, false, true);
            spriteBatch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ZERO);
            spriteBatch.draw(mask, 0,0);
            Gdx.gl20.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
            spriteBatch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_DST_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ZERO);
            spriteBatch.draw(texture, 0,0);
            spriteBatch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        buffer.end();
    spriteBatch.end();      
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(buffer.getColorBufferTexture(), getX(), getY());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a look at your images, it looks like:

- The alpha of the mask is in complete control of the output alpha
- You want the alpha of the background image to also be taken into account

In other words, you only want alpha where both images have alpha.

---

I haven't yet been able to look into more of the blending functions and how they work, and may update with further details on how to achieve your goals as I figure it out, but maybe knowing what you are trying to accomplish will help you figure it out before I get to it.

[How to do blending in LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347456/how-to-do-blending-in-libgdx) - this question seems interesting, combining the source and destination images in a grid to show the effects.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you answer. I know what i'm trying to accomplish i don't know how to do it. i think i tried all possible blending functions. so i guess there is something more than that need to be done. in the link you posted even it was answered it is a different scenario. as you specified.